# Looping through variable names as strings, and destroying them

Tags: javascript, variables, casting, eval

I have a list of variables (let's call them `obj1`, `obj2`, etc.). I would like to loop through all of them and, if they exist, destroy them. Obviously `.destroy()` is an external call.

Why does this work:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var obj = "obj" + i.toString();
    if (window[obj]) {
        window[obj].destroy();
    }
}
```

But this doesn't:

```
var objs = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    objs.push("obj" + i.toString());
    if (objs[i]) {
        objs[i].destroy(); //throws a TypeError
    }
}
```

And is there a better solution that's more like the second, and doesn't involve accessing global scope via `window`? Please don't say `eval()`.

Comment: Presumably the objects being pointed to by variables like `obj1` have a `destroy()` method. But the strings beings held in `objs[i]` don't. When you use `window['obj1']` you are referencing the object this window property is pointing to. That's not the case with an array holding strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`objs.push("obj" + i.toString());` will push a *string* to the `objs` array. But strings don't have a `.destroy` property. In comparison, `window["obj" + i.toString()]` tries to reference a *property* on the window object by that name. (The value in that property, or `undefined`, will be pushed to `objs`)

It would be better to restructure your script so that rather than searching through the `window` object for variables of a certain name, you instead put all the related variables into an *array* at the start, so that you can then iterate through the array and `destroy()` them directly:

```
const objs = [
  <someObj1>,
  <someObj2>,
  ...
];
objs.forEach(obj => obj.destroy());
```

Comment: Ended up doing precisely this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you are using the string as the key to the object window, like this:

```
window.obj1
```

and then calling destroy on it.

The second example doesn't work because what you are pushing into the array is a string,

```
"obj" + i.toString()
```

You are calling destroy in the string itself since you created an array of strings. That's why you get the TypeError.

Answer (score 1):

If you bother to use window object, why don't you clone it to a new object called container? That may work for you. Thanks

```
const container=window;

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var obj = "obj" + i.toString();
    if (container[obj]) {
        container[obj].destroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid using the window object entirely, cloned or otherwise. This is an interesting approach, though. Thank you.

Comment: You should declare those objects in a scope in the first place, then you can totally avoid window object.